# How to solve this using residue calculus?

Tags: integration, contour-integration, residue-calculus

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \, \frac{\sin(k)}{k}e^{ikx} dk$$

I'm not too sure how to go about this. I think there is a pole at $z=0$ but then the residue is also$ =0 $ so i'm a bit lost :/

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The contribute given by the imaginary part of $e^{ikx}$ vanishes by symmetry and

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(k)\cos(kx)}{k}\,dk = \frac{1}{2}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin((1+x)k)}{k}\,dk+\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin((1-x)k)}{k}\,dk\right]$$
equals 
$$ \frac{\pi}{2}\left[\text{sign}(1+x)+\text{sign}(1-x)\right]=\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}0 & \text{if} & |x|>1\\ \frac{\pi}{2} & \text{if} & |x|=1 \\ \pi & \text{if} & |x|<1\end{array}\right. $$
by the well-known lemma

$$ \forall x\in\mathbb{R},\qquad \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(kx)}{k}\,dk = \pi\,\text{sign}(x).$$

Comment: How is the OP supposed to know the result of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(ak)}{k}dk$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 Seems like a common integral, not to hard to prove anyways.

Comment: @user1952009: exactly, detail explained anyway.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I know there is a way with the residue theorem, but I never remember it. Personally I use the Fourier inversion theorem.

Comment: In every cases, you can't answer this way, not giving any reference

Comment: @user1952009 I think this is fine.  We aren't expected to explain every detail, just enough to answer the question and provide guidance.

Comment: @user1952009: I do not agree. If in a geometry proof one uses the Pythagorean theorem, he/she does not have to prove it again. If some lemma is well-known, it is well-known and it can be used.